# cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="No such configuration property: "bootstrap_servers""}

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-python

I am trying to produce AVRO data to Kafka topic through python producer script, I already installed python dependencies avro-python3 and confluent_kafka, however when running this script i got below error:

```
  File "./kafka_producer_avro.py", line 24, in <module>
    kafka_producer_obj = Producer(kafka_config_obj)
cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="No such configuration property: "bootstrap_servers""}
```

After investigation i found that I should install (libsasl2-dev and libsasl2-modules) dependencies.
(`sudo yum install gcc libffi-devel python-devel python-pip python-wheel openssl-devel libsasl2-devel openldap-devel`), but i got below
`Error: Unable to find a match: python-devel python-pip python-wheel libsasl2-devel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your shown error has nothing to do with OS packages.

It's `bootstrap.servers`, not with an underscore. Also, the Kafka module is with hyphen, not underscore.

Docs - https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-clients/python/current/overview.html

You can additionally install `fastavro` with pip.

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer, it works after modifying kafka object from 
kafka_config_obj = {'bootstrap_servers': KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS} to
kafka_config_obj = {'bootstrap.servers': KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONS} and i didn't need to install the fastavro package :)

Comment: My point with fastavro is that it'll run quicker if you're serializing many records, not to fix the error you're getting

Comment: Okay Great, i will try again to install it as I faced an error while trying the last time.
Thanks again :)